# Extjs fileuploadfield default browser tooltip issue

Tags: extjs, file-upload, tooltip

I am working in Extjs. I have fileuploadfield. It shows default browser tooltip as 'no files chosen' in chrome and 'no files selected'in firefox.
I want to disable or hide this tooltip. So how to perform this in extjs. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a buttonConfig to your filefield object and specify these settings to get around the default for Chrome. I haven't yet been able to find a way to get rid of it in Firefox.

```
                {
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    buttonConfig: {
                        xtype: 'filebutton',
                        text: 'MyButton',
                        tooltip: ' ',
                        tooltipType: 'title'
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanx for help. It works for me also in case of chrome browser. But wanted to hide it in firefox also. So if anybody knows,please help

Comment: Hello, Above code works for chrome . But on MAC operating system, tooltip box is still get displayed with blank text.